# Unity- Azure Spatial Anchors - Cosmos DB - How can to add extra JSON Column to the database

Tags: unity-game-engine, azure-cosmosdb, azure-spatial-anchors

[image]

[image]

So I need an extra column called Totems which is just a string or JSON. I made this column in the data editor in the Azure Cosmos DB but I still need to fix this in the code and create a GET/POST for Totem. I found this file called TableEntity as shown in the picture but I am unable to edit this metadata file. I dont have access to edit this. So now I am stuck...

Answer (score 2):

It appears that this was [cross-posted to the ASA GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-spatial-anchors-samples/issues/311) and the response was provided there. To add extra data to these entries, you'll want to modify [this file](https://github.com/Azure/azure-spatial-anchors-samples/blob/79dc2ee96d027f9eeeab56767b5013d533bced63/Sharing/SharingServiceSample/Data/CosmosDbCache.cs#L12).